# downloading csv file button from a website

Tags: python, selenium

I am facing a problem of downloading a csv file from a website that requires login. I have successfully logged in using Selenium. However I don't know how to download the csv file by clicking on a button. I have tried to inspect but i Failed. plus there is no copy url of the csv file that is provided in the website. can anyone help me with the code. this is so far what I have written.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

chromedriver = "/webdrivers/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get('https://user.sensogram.com/signin')   #driver.get(url)-- We get 
url by using driver which we initialy load.    
print ("Opened sensogram")
time.sleep(5)    #Just wait for sometime.
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='usernameSignIn']") 
#Find email textaera.
email.send_keys('****')  #Send email to this text area. 
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='passwordSignIn']") 
#Find password textarea.
password.send_keys('*******')   #send password to the password field.
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@ng- 
click='submitted=true']")  #Find login button.
button.click()      #Click on login button.
```

and this is the code I get when i inspect the csv file button.

```
<g class="highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton highcharts-button-normal" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:center;font-size:12;font-weight:500;" stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(399,8)"><title>Chart context menu</title><rect fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)" class=" highcharts-button-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="100" height="32" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"></rect><text x="7" style="font-weight:normal;color:#fff;fill:#fff;" y="19"><tspan>Download CSV</tspan></text></g>

<rect fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)" class=" highcharts-button-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="100" height="32" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"></rect>

<text x="7" style="font-weight:normal;color:#fff;fill:#fff;" y="19"> 
<tspan>Download CSV</tspan></text>

<tspan>Download CSV</tspan>
```

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="tspan" and .="Download CSV"]').click()`

Comment: didn't work got an error. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[name()="tspan" and .="Download CSV"]"}

Comment: Try to use [Implicit/Explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: after adding driver.implicitly_wait(5)  I got an error. Message: unknown error: Element <tspan>...</tspan> is not clickable at point (900, 577). Other element would receive the click: <div class="page-loading ng-scope" ng-if="showPreloader" style="">...</div>

Comment: When authorization completed do you see some kind of blurred loading screen? [something like this](https://8nf7w3gwglk2ygsyo3x6iahc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/rough-draft.jpg)?

Comment: no i don't see anything

Comment: when i write I get an error that say Element <tspan>...</tspan> is not clickable at point (900, 577). Other element would receive the click: <div class="page-loading ng-scope" ng-if="showPreloader" style="">...</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath:

```
//tspan[text() = 'Download CSV']
```

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tspan[text() = 'Download CSV']"}

Comment: also better to make sure that the element is visible before clicking on it. If this is not the case, maybe add a wait statement before interacting with the element.

Comment: i still got an error after adding a wait statement saying    Message: unknown error: Element <tspan>...</tspan> is not clickable at point (900, 577). Other element would receive the click: <div class="page-loading ng-scope" ng-if="showPreloader" style="">...</div>

Comment: it seems you might need to wait until the other element becomes invisible i.e. invisibility_of_element_located(locatorOfOtherElement)

Comment: how do I write that based on the code written up there?

Comment: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`
`wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,”page-loading”)))`